# Boost Volume for iPad

Tags: ipad, sound-volume

I have been using an iPad's speech synathesis for a project and we're finding that the volume just isn't loud enought - are there ways of boosting the loudness without just adding external speakers? The iPad is jailbroken, and I'm willing to consider approaches that reduce the lifespan of the device.

Comment: You're talking about boosting the volume of the built in speaker - correct?

Comment: Yes - definately the built in speaker.

Comment: Put it in a big bowl.

Answer (score 3):

There is a neat trick you can do with a book, or other hard surface. (Ideal results are achieved with a concave surface.) Place the iPad speaker facing the book/surface. Some sound will reflect off the book, and join the forwards traveling sound, effectively boosting the volume by a small margin.

Other than that, consider placing the iPad almost touching the microphone of whatever recording device you are using.

(There is probably an app on Cydia to boost volume, but my iPad is not jailbroken, so I am not sure)

Answer (score 1):

Just heard about "Volume Boost Free" on I think mac weekly, it was one of the guests app of the week. I just installed the app and does seem to increase the volume. The app is in the app store and is free, it is not a universal app but it does work on my iPad 2.

link below

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/volume-boost-free/id421816838?mt=8

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the SoundJaw. It's a plastic concave clip-on device for the iPad 2 that redirects the sound to the front. It works with the magnetic smart cover. Search for 'soundjaw ipad'. The price is less than $15.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Instead of directing people to search themselves can you please provide a link to the product page?